# Why can I not add a date as a title in terra::rast?

Tags: r, plot, terra

I'm slowly transitioning over to `terra::rast` from `raster`, and I noticed I am not able to add a date to my title. I have figured out a workaround (reassign to character), but I'm wondering why this doesn't work when it worked in `raster`? The error message is not too informative.

Here's an example:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2015-06-24"), as.Date("2016-01-01"), by=1)
test <- terra::rast(nrows=100, ncols=100, xmin=0, xmax=100, ymin=0, ymax=100,
                      crs="+proj=utm +zone=46 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs", 
                      resolution=10)
values(test) <- runif(10000)
plot(test, col=viridis::plasma(11), main=dates[4], breaks = c(seq(0, 1, by=0.1)))

Error in if (main != "") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

This code works when doing the following:

```
plot(test, col=viridis::plasma(11), main=as.character(dates[4]), 
     breaks = c(seq(0, 1, by=0.1)))
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is exactly the problem. At some point in the code, the `main` argument is tested to see if it is the empty string `""` with the line `if(main != "")`. But comparing a `Date` class object to an empty string gives a missing value `NA` result:

```
Sys.Date() == ""
# [1] NA
```

And an `if()` statement throws an error if you give it `NA`:

```
if(NA){}
# Error in if (NA) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

So the code is assuming `main` is a `character` class object. This is documented, the `?terra::plot` description of the `main` argument is:

> `character`. Main plot titles (one for each layer to be plotted)

Luckily (see comments), it seems like support for dates was added recently, so you can install the new version from Github!

Comment: That feature was added 2 weeks ago. So one can either use the development version of `terra`: `install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')`, or with the current version, do `plot(x, main=as.character(dates[4]))`

Comment: Awesome, thank you both!